# Add an arbiter to mongodb ReplicaSet failed

Tags: replication, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and this is my second post in order to build a test cluster and gain knowledge at the same time. I have a **3 nodes cluster** holding server **MONGO2, MONGO3** and **MONGOARB1**. MONGO2 and MONGO3 are in **replicaset "rs0"** and works great :

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "version" : 3,
        "term" : 9,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "MONGO2:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "secondaryDelaySecs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "MONGO3:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "secondaryDelaySecs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
```

I'd like to add an arbiter to my  PSA cluster as described here :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/

[image]

So following the documentation:

- Create a specific directory => **OK** (C:\MONGO\arb)
- Start the arbiter, specifying the data directory and the name of the replica set to join => **OK** : `./mongod.exe --port 27017 --dbpath C:\MONGO\arb --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all`

> "msg":"Failed to refresh key
> cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read
> concern until replica set is finished
> initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24200}}

- Connect to the primary and add the arbiter to the replica set. => **KO** `rs.addArb("MONGOARB1:27017");`

After this last command nothing happen and the error log show followings messages:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.038+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21352,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"replSetReconfig admin command received from client","attr":{"newConfig":{"_id":"rs0","version":4,"term":9,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"MONGO2:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1,"tags":{},"secondaryDelaySecs":0,"votes":1},{"_id":1,"host":"MONGO3:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1,"tags":{},"secondaryDelaySecs":0,"votes":1},{"_id":2,"host":"MONGOARB1:27017","arbiterOnly":true}],"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"settings":{"chainingAllowed":true,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":2000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":10,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"61d5799d9249ea1cc550e79d"}}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.038+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015313, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Replication config state is Steady, starting reconfig"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.038+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReconfiguring","oldState":"ConfigSteady"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.038+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigSteady","oldState":"ConfigReconfiguring"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.246+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4508702, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Waiting for the current config to propagate to a majority of nodes"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.246+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":51815,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Waiting for the last committed optime in the previous config to be committed in the current config","attr":{"configOplogCommitmentOpTime":{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1642004542,"i":2}},"t":9}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.246+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4508701, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"The current replica set config is committed","attr":{"configVersion":3,"configTerm":9,"configWaitDurationMillis":0,"oplogWaitDurationMillis":0,"configOplogCommitmentOpTime":{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1642004542,"i":2}},"t":9}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.246+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21352,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"replSetReconfig admin command received from client","attr":{"newConfig":{"_id":"rs0","version":4,"term":9,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"MONGO2:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1,"tags":{},"secondaryDelaySecs":0,"votes":1},{"_id":1,"host":"MONGO3:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1,"tags":{},"secondaryDelaySecs":0,"votes":1},{"_id":2,"host":"MONGOARB1:27017","arbiterOnly":true}],"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"settings":{"chainingAllowed":true,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":2000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":10,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"61d5799d9249ea1cc550e79d"}}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.246+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015313, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Replication config state is Steady, starting reconfig"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.246+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReconfiguring","oldState":"ConfigSteady"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-12T17:33:29.246+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigSteady","oldState":"ConfigReconfiguring"}}
```

And after a while the command fail with:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.addArb("MONGOARB1:27017");
assert.soon failed: function() {
        var cfg = hostport;

        var local = db.getSiblingDB("local");
        assert(local.system.replset.count() <= 1,
               "error: local.system.replset has unexpected contents");
        var c = local.system.replset.findOne();
        assert(c, "no config object retrievable from local.system.replset");

        const attemptedVersion = c.version++;

        var max = 0;
        for (var i in c.members) {
            // Omit 'newlyAdded' field if it exists in the config.
            delete c.members[i].newlyAdded;
            if (c.members[i]._id > max)
                max = c.members[i]._id;
        }
        if (isString(hostport)) {
            cfg = {_id: max + 1, host: hostport};
            if (arb)
                cfg.arbiterOnly = true;
        } else if (arb == true) {
            throw Error(
                "Expected first parameter to be a host-and-port string of arbiter, but got " +
                tojson(hostport));
        }

        if (cfg._id == null) {
            cfg._id = max + 1;
        }
        c.members.push(cfg);

        res = self._runCmd({replSetReconfig: c});
        if (res === "") {
            // _runCmd caught an exception.
            return true;
        }
        if (res.ok) {
            return true;
        }
        if (res.code === ErrorCodes.ConfigurationInProgress ||
            res.code === ErrorCodes.CurrentConfigNotCommittedYet) {
            return false;  // keep retrying
        }
        if (res.code === ErrorCodes.NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible) {
            // We will retry only if this error was due to our config version being too low.
            const cfgState = local.system.replset.findOne();
            if (cfgState.version >= attemptedVersion) {
                return false;  // keep retrying
            }
        }
        // Take no action on other errors.
        return true;
    } : {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Reconfig attempted to install a config that would change the implicit default write concern. Use the setDefaultRWConcern command to set a cluster-wide write concern and try the reconfig again.",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1642005752, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1642005752, 1)
} The hang analyzer is automatically called in assert.soon functions. If you are *expecting* assert.soon to possibly fail, call assert.soon with {runHangAnalyzer: false} as the fifth argument (you can fill unused arguments with `undefined`). Running hang analyzer from assert.soon.
Skipping runHangAnalyzer: no TestData (not running from resmoke)
Error: assert.soon failed: function() {
        var cfg = hostport;

        var local = db.getSiblingDB("local");
        assert(local.system.replset.count() <= 1,
               "error: local.system.replset has unexpected contents");
        var c = local.system.replset.findOne();
        assert(c, "no config object retrievable from local.system.replset");

        const attemptedVersion = c.version++;

        var max = 0;
        for (var i in c.members) {
            // Omit 'newlyAdded' field if it exists in the config.
            delete c.members[i].newlyAdded;
            if (c.members[i]._id > max)
                max = c.members[i]._id;
        }
        if (isString(hostport)) {
            cfg = {_id: max + 1, host: hostport};
            if (arb)
                cfg.arbiterOnly = true;
        } else if (arb == true) {
            throw Error(
                "Expected first parameter to be a host-and-port string of arbiter, but got " +
                tojson(hostport));
        }

        if (cfg._id == null) {
            cfg._id = max + 1;
        }
        c.members.push(cfg);

        res = self._runCmd({replSetReconfig: c});
        if (res === "") {
            // _runCmd caught an exception.
            return true;
        }
        if (res.ok) {
            return true;
        }
        if (res.code === ErrorCodes.ConfigurationInProgress ||
            res.code === ErrorCodes.CurrentConfigNotCommittedYet) {
            return false;  // keep retrying
        }
        if (res.code === ErrorCodes.NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible) {
            // We will retry only if this error was due to our config version being too low.
            const cfgState = local.system.replset.findOne();
            if (cfgState.version >= attemptedVersion) {
                return false;  // keep retrying
            }
        }
        // Take no action on other errors.
        return true;
    } : {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Reconfig attempted to install a config that would change the implicit default write concern. Use the setDefaultRWConcern command to set a cluster-wide write concern and try the reconfig again.",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1642005752, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1642005752, 1)
} The hang analyzer is automatically called in assert.soon functions. If you are *expecting* assert.soon to possibly fail, call assert.soon with {runHangAnalyzer: false} as the fifth argument (you can fill unused arguments with `undefined`). :
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:20:14
assert.soon@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:382:17
rs.add@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1632:5
rs.addArb@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1704:12
@(shell):1:1
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Note that if I use the command "rs.add" it works great to add the node as it was a replicaset member holding datas.

Comment: Did you try `rs.add( { host: "MONGOARB1:27017", arbiterOnly: true } )`?

Comment: Is folder `C:\MONGO\arb` empty? Compare config files, there could be difference. Option [enableMajorityReadConcern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-replication.enableMajorityReadConcern) has been removed in MongoDB version 5, do you still have it set?

Comment: What is the version of MongoDB you are working with? What is the output from the `rs.status()` and `db.hello()` methods?

Comment: @Wenfried rs.add( { host: "MONGOARB1:27017", arbiterOnly: true } ); returns the same behavior. C:\MONGO\arb is empty when created but filed with several files after the command ./mongod.exe --port 27017 --dbpath C:\MONGO\arb --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all (collection.wt, mongod.lock, storage.bson etc) - I am not using the option enableMajorityReadConcern.

Comment: @prasad before and after adding the arbiter rs.satus() & db.hello() returns the current config, it is up and running.

Comment: This looks all normal. Do you run the same version on all hosts? Check with `mongod --version` You may open a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/issues/

Comment: A workaround might be this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70636714/mongodb-unable-to-reach-primary-for-set-new-replica-set-name/70636906#70636906 - but it should work the way you try to do it.

Comment: Note that the error message says "Reconfig attempted to install a config that would change the implicit default write concern. Use the setDefaultRWConcern command to set a cluster-wide write concern and try the reconfig again."  What was the previous default?

Answer (score 3):

In your primary mongodb shell, execute following:

```
db.adminCommand({
   "setDefaultRWConcern" : 1,
   "defaultWriteConcern" : {
     "w" : 1
   }
 })
```

this should resolve the issue.

Comment: The above command solves the issue. It would be better if you added an explanation to your answer of what exactly the above command does.

Answer (score 2):

As Mohit mentioned above, quick answer could be

```
db.adminCommand({
   "setDefaultRWConcern" : 1,
   "defaultWriteConcern" : {
     "w" : 1
   }
 })
```

But make sure you understand what [WriteConcern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/#std-label-wc-ack-behavior) is.
In short to implement TransactionalModel Mongo enforce replica/shards members to ackowledge/confirm Write operation.

In replicaset w could be

- 0 if no acknowledgment from any members of replicaset required
- 1 if standalone/primary node only need to acknowledge write operation.
- "majority" if majority should acknowledge. (its 2 f.e. in 3 members ReplicaSet)
- X if required...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on existing cluster with mongo 5.0.12. I intentionally installed mongo 6.0 on arbiter to upgrade all nodes to 6.0. There was no errors, except for

```
"msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24200}}
```

So, one should join member with matching version and upgrade secondaries only after sync.